# Azure: Moving from VM to Azure Functions/IotHub/SQL/Rest API

Tags: python, nginx, azure, iot

so here is my project: I have a temperatue sensor wired to a ESP32 which uses MQTTS to connect to a Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine on port 8883. On the VM is an Nginx Server running which uses uWSGI and a python App. The App collects the data through MQTTS, saves it in a SQL database and runs a REST API for external connections to querry the data from the database.

What i need to do, is change from using a Virtual Machine to Azure Functionalities (like SQL database, iotHub, RestAPI..)
What i managed to do till now is connecting my ESP32 device to iotHub. So i need to know what should be the next step? Should i use iotHub message Trigger? How can i save the data in a SQL database? How can i create a Rest API?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Iot Hub then you have two options:

1a. Use Azure Event Grid and go [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview), you will see that as Event Publishers you will see support for IoT Hub as well. When a message is sent to IoT Hub, Event Grid will know IoT Hub has a new message and then you can configure a Receiver\Subscriber\Listener in a form of Logic Apps or Functions. In Logic App or Function you will see the event notification and then using that notification read off the message from IoT Hub namespace and process that message which in your case would be to store in Azure SQL.

1b. Rather than using Event Grid you can use Azure Function triggers, Event Grid is recommended as it has Retry and failure detection and you can have multiple subscribers for that one publisher plus you can setup from the Azure Portal easily and if everything is working fine and also setup Filters. On the trigger you would read the message from the IoT Hub namespace and process it by storing it in SQL DB.

- a very different approach, that would be to use [Azure Data Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/data-explorer-overview) with Event Hub or IoT Hub. Data Explorer is built for scenarios like this and would be the best and cheapest option and almost zero code.
- Send messages to Event Hub,
- Create ADX Cluster and then DB, use [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/create-cluster-database-portal), use the cheapest option here which is the DevTest one
- To Ingest data you will have to create a table for which you will need to have a table schema and that you can create by using the built-in simple ingestion tool from [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer/create-a-table-with-the-1-click-experience/ba-p/1606607).
- When you have created the table from the sample JSON file then you can setup your continuous data ingestion connection, use [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-no-code?tabs=diagnostic-metrics#connect-an-event-hub-to-azure-data-explorer).
- After doing the ingestion then comes time for query, from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/web-query-data).
- You can connect to Power BI and visualize your data and use ADX's REST APIs to connect with the underlying data as well. As it is a toold for big data exploration so you can use it from Time Series analysis, forecasting and so much more.

In both cases I would recommend using the capture option for the Iot Hub as it will store the message as it is received in Azure BLOB Storage as well as to have a backup of all RAW messages. Also you can use both Event Hub and Iot Hub, I would recommend Event Hub if it is one-way and it is a bit cheaper as well.